# mouse over droop on menu item

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Ok, please bear with me as its as confusing for me to explain as it may be for you guys to understand... but!

What i want to do, is similar to how on the tabs for chrome you get the weird 'Aura' think following the mouse cursor, but what i actually want to do is have it so that where ever your mouse cursor goes you get a 'droop' on the menu item. I want it to be subtle, so please see example image here

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX7r6.jpg)
And the droop needs to follow the cursor when hovering over the area its in.

I have a jsfiddle of a VERY VERY crude idea...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andeh/BfLAh/1918/)
codesnippet:

```
$(document)
.mousemove(function(e){
    $(".image").css({left:e.pageX-75, top:e.pageY-31});
});
```

i cant seem to find an example of what i want either, but that could be due to me not really knowing what to ask...

Hope people can help!

Andy

Comment: hmm I would try that with SVG :D here is a cute [Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) , hope this helps

Comment: awwwww man...  that means ide have to learn how to animate the svg points on mouse move... though i can see i would only really need to animate one point... might give that a go and see how i get on. Ive got some time to kill lol

Comment: good luck :) yeah i know this will take u a while, but at the end it will be smooth and flawless, also in the future you`ll know svg, well at least have ideas on how to use it :D

Comment: I have an idea on how to make it, i`ll do it later and post it as answer :) wish me luck :D

Comment: sweet! ive spent all afternoon staring at the screen and just cant get my head around it... its not illustrator by any stretch of the imagination! i look forward to your result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/MYqKPw) it is not perfect but it should give you the general idea, I kinda made in a hurry, sorry for this

```
var divPos = {};
$("svg").mousemove(function(e){
    var position = $(this).offset();
    divPos = {
        left: e.pageX - position.left,
        top: e.pageY - position.top
    };
  var d = $(this).children('path').attr('d');
  var q = d.split(',');
  var q2 = q[1].split(" ");
  var qX = divPos.left;
  var qY = divPos.top;
  var dRebuild = q[0]+",Q"+qX+" "+qY+","+q[2];
  var svgParent = $(this);
  svgParent.children('path').attr('d',dRebuild+" ");
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    dRebuild = q[0]+",Q0 0,"+q[2];
    svgParent.children('path').attr('d',dRebuild+" ");
  });
});
```

Comment: genuinelly amazing, thanks for this! i'll be playing around with that today to get the mouseleave smother, but apart from that i cant thank you enough! :D

Answer (score 0):

Do u want to show the curved design on while mouse we hover the menu?.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
```

mouse hover effect will apply complete document.change this to menu div

Html:

```
<div id="menuitem">
<img class="image" src="http://staging.tradeinchecker.com/andydev/w1t/drip.png"/>
Home</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#menuitem").mousemove(function(e){
$(".image").css({left:e.pageX-75});});
```

try this

Comment: the mousemove for the image is only really for an example of what i want. It needs to be fluid, so the best option would be for the SVG animation that was mentioned as a comment. 

Again, its hard to explain what i'm actually after, but i'm not going to be using an image lol

Comment: see this link.https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/  this page have different shapes this might help you .find the shape then play with css.

Comment: you wouldn't be able to do what im trying to do with css shapes, as they are too rigid of an element. they cant really be manipulated by mouse position unfortunately.
Thanks though!